# How to add serial no in IQueryable query in LinQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my method that returns ***IQueryable*** query. I want to generate serial no based on number of records.

```
public IQueryable<CompanyModel> GetCompanyData()
{

   var query = (from e in Context.tblCompany
                         where e.Cmp_Id == this.CompanyId
                         && e.TenantId == this.TenantId
                         select new CompanyModel()
                         {
                             CmpId = e.Cmp_Id,
                             SrNo = 0,
                         });
   return query;
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you?  What have you tried and what isn't working?  What specifically are you asking?

Comment: What do you mean `Serial No`? The serial number is the unique number that identifies a part or product. Do you mean a row number? `Select()` has an overload `Select((item,index))`that passes the item index to the delegate. You can use this right before you execute the query by enumerating it or calling `ToList()`tc

Comment: Serial no means SrNo field display value from 1 to upto no of records

For Example : 

Sr No Company Id
1          1
2           2
3           3

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem. What are you trying to achieve? There's probably an alternative without serial number.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code may it help you

```
public IQueryable<CompanyModel> GetCompanyData()
{

List<CompanyModel> query = (from e in Context.tblCompany
                         where e.Cmp_Id == this.CompanyId
                         && e.TenantId == this.TenantId
                         select new CompanyModel()
                         {
                             CmpId = e.Cmp_Id,
                             SrNo = 0,
                         }).ToList();

 int counter=0;
 query.Foreach(x=>x.SrNo = counter++);

return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the only way to have sequence number generated by the query itself is using "Select" method overload with 2 parameters, however it doesn't work with IQueryable, so your query will look like:

```
Context.tblCompany.Where(e => e.Cmp_Id == this.CompanyId && e.TenantId == this.TenantId)
    .Select(e => new { CmpId = e.Cmp_Id })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((e, i) => new CompanyModel { CmpId = e.CmpId, SrNo = i });
```

Obviously, this sequence number will be generated on the client and the resulting expression can't be treated as IQueryable anymore. At the same time, the part before "AsEnumerable" will be successfully translated into SQL.